# How to construct ordered datatypes in SML automatically

Tags: metaprogramming, sml, smlnj, algebraic-data-types

I'd like to know if there is any way to create a function that, given a list of `names`/`identifiers` e.g. `[Monday, Tuesday, ...]`, automatically creates a `datatype day = Monday | Tuesday | ...` and a function next such that `next Monday = Tuesday`, `next Tuesday = Wednesday`, ... preserving (and reflecting) the order of the identifiers in the list. I know I can do this by hand, but I was wondering if datatype declarations are even possible within functions. If this isn't possible in SML, what are some languages (preferably functional) that allow this?

Comment: Not possible in SML (what would the type of such a function be? There isn't an SML type whose *values* are types). [Python functions can create classes](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-metaprogramming-python/index.html), but that probably isn't sufficiently functional for you. Maybe Lisp macros might interest you. Along that line, perhaps `clojure` (which is based on Lisp but is more functional) might have something. What you are trying to do is unlikely to play nicely with type inference.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in Standard ML.  (In some implementations, you can actually write a file and read it at run time using `use`, but that is generally frown upon.)

Haskell can do this:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun deriving (Enum, Show)
Prelude> succ Mon
Tue
Prelude> succ Sun
*** Exception: succ{Day}: tried to take `succ' of last tag in enumeration
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:5:62 in interactive:Ghci2
```

The `deriving` clause tells the compiler to automatically implement the [`Enum` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum), which provides the `succ` function.  (The [`Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) class is only there so that we can print the results.)  `deriving` is an ad-hoc mechanism built into the Haskell compiler, but GHC provides many meta-programming facilities.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a case of dynamically taking a list and at run time creating a new enumeration type.

Comment: I obviously assumed that the list was presented at compile time. Maybe the question is unclear about that part.

Comment: The question itself wasn't clear on that point. Your answer is a good answer to one interpretation (+1).